# twitter bootstrap button toggle does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have the bootstrap-button.js and have this markup, but when i click on the button, it does not toggle it to show that it has been clicked. any tips as to what is missing?

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" data-toggle-name="checkbox_group">
    <button class="btn" id="chkbox1"  type="button" value="1Fail" data-toggle="button"> 1 Failure </button>
    <button class="btn" id="chkbox2"  type="button" value="2Fail" data-toggle="button"> 2 Failure </button>
    <button class="btn" id="chkbox3" type="button" value="OtherFail" data-toggle="button"> Other Failure </button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="checkbox_group" value="1"/>
</div>
```

second part of the question is how to get the data into javascript as to which button was clicked? if 1Fail was clicked, it should toggle and js code to detect that 1Fail was clicked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Idiot check: Every issue I've had with bootstrap was because I was using an old version of jQuery. Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: I ran into this issue earlier and already double chkd that jquery version is latest and compatible with twitter bootstrap - thx for the note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you added `data-toggle="button"` to every check button, which is not necessary. Because you already have `data-toggle="buttons-checkbox"` in the outer `div` element .

So change it to look like this:

```
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" data-toggle-name="checkbox_group">
        <button class="btn" id="chkbox1"  type="button" value="1Fail" > 1 Failure </button>
        <button class="btn" id="chkbox2"  type="button" value="2Fail" > 2 Failure </button>
        <button class="btn" id="chkbox3" type="button" value="OtherFail" > Other Failure </button>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="checkbox_group" value="1"/>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I didn't notice your second question. When a button is clicked an `active` class will be added to it, so you can detect this with jQuery's `hasClass` method.

Comment: For the second part of my question, i solved it by doing this: $('#chkbox1.active').val()